# Setup NSView for printing under macOs

Tags: swift, macos, printing, nsview

I've managed to setup a function that allows me to print out a list from my macOs app. 
I've set up a function that takes a String containing HTML

```
   func makePDF(markup: String, amount: Int) {
    let directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let printOpts: [NSPrintInfo.AttributeKey: Any] = [NSPrintInfo.AttributeKey.jobDisposition: NSPrintInfo.JobDisposition.save, NSPrintInfo.AttributeKey.jobSavingURL: directoryURL]
    let printInfo = NSPrintInfo(dictionary: printOpts)
    printInfo.horizontalPagination = NSPrintInfo.PaginationMode.autoPagination
    printInfo.verticalPagination = NSPrintInfo.PaginationMode.autoPagination
    printInfo.topMargin = 20.0
    printInfo.leftMargin = 20.0
    printInfo.rightMargin = 20.0
    printInfo.bottomMargin = 20.0

    let view = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 560, height: (60 + 36 * amount)))

    if let htmlData = markup.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        let attrStr = NSAttributedString(html: htmlData, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:
            String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)

        let frameRect = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 560, height: (60 + 36 * amount))
        let textField = NSTextField(frame: frameRect)
        textField.attributedStringValue = attrStr!
        view.addSubview(textField)

        let printOperation = NSPrintOperation(view: view, printInfo: printInfo)
        printOperation.showsPrintPanel = true
        printOperation.showsProgressPanel = true
        printOperation.run()

    }
}
```

However I have trouble with the correct layout and set up of a Page. The other thing is that I have not managed to have a HTML with a border ( The border attribute is ignored)

Are there some best practices to set up a printed page (US-Letter or DIN A4) that fits without having overflowing border to a next page?

How can I manage to have a border in my HTML Table to be printed out?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of `NSPrintInfo.PaginationMode`.

Comment: Thanks @Willeke I will look into it. However that does only solve half of my problems.

Comment: I don't think HTML experts will read this question. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: I don‘t think that my question relates to HTML experts as it is more for macOS experts familiar with NSAttributedString and how to make a table visible with a border.
But that‘s just a guess.

Comment: I don't think `NSAttributedString` experts will read this question.